# Using jQuery in Chrome extension: load in background, access in popup

Tags: jquery, background, popup, google-chrome-extension

I am making a [PageAction](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html) Chrome extension with a popup and a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

I want to use jQuery in the popup to manipulate its DOM for presenting data (which I am scraping from the website itself using jQuery injected as a content script). I know I can load jQuery directly in popup.html and use it. However, I wanted to see if I could load jQuery only once in the background page and access it in the popup, rather than loading it each time the popup is opened.

For this, I tried the following in the popup:

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var $ = background.jQuery;
$("#testID").innerHTML = "testing jQuery";
```

but it didn't work - `$("#testID")` was undefined. I checked that jQuery was loaded in the background page, and using alternate names for $, e.g. jq, jQuery etc. didn't work either.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Received your merge request, but the accounts you linked are the same.

Comment: @TimPost - Hi Tim, My unregistered user number is 708921, and my registered user number is 709233. Please merge my unregistered account into my registered account. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#testID", document).html("testing jQuery");
```

I don't think there is a way to permanently change default context, so you will need to pass `document` as a second parameter to all your selectors.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and the obvious followup is to define, e.g. `var _$ = function(str) { return chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().jQuery(str,document); }`